# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null at playVid

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm getting errors for play and pause.. both saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null at playVid"

My code below, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<button onclick="playVid()"  type="button">Play Video</button>
<button onclick="pauseVid()" type="button">Pause Video</button><br> 

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176">
  <source src="<?php echo $video ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function playVid() {
  vid.play();
}

function pauseVid() {
  vid.pause();
}

function menuAnimate(x) {
  $(".menu-wrap").toggleClass("open");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always run the script after all the HTML elements are loaded

What happens when you run the script first

```html
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
```

Since the body of the element is not loaded, there exists no element which has
an id `myVideo` and vid is initialised to `null`

Now when you click on the button `playVid()` is called but fails to execute `vid.play()` since `vid` is initialised to null

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <button onclick="playVid()"  type="button">Play Video</button>
  <button onclick="pauseVid()" type="button">Pause Video</button><br> 

  <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176">
    <source src="<?php echo $video ?>" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

    function playVid() {
      vid.play();
    }

    function pauseVid() {
      vid.pause();
    }

    function menuAnimate(x) {
      $(".menu-wrap").toggleClass("open");
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```